# get checkbox array value in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen a few posts asking the same question but I can't make it work. I'm quite new to angular so I would need help.
I'm trying to insert a new income with tags.
I get thoses tags from a service and display them like this :

```
<label ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tags_chosen" name="tags_chosen[tag]" ng-true-value="<%tag.id%>"/> <%tag.name%>
</label>
```

When I try to get back the checkbox values in angular, it doesn't work :

```
 this.addIncome = function($scope) {
 var data = {
        'project_id':$scope.project_id,
        'amount':$scope.amount,
        'payment_date':$scope.payment_date,
        'tags':$scope.tag_chosen,
        'description':$scope.description,
        'type':$scope.type
    };

    return $http.post(URL.BASE_API + 'income/store',data).
    success(function(response) {
        ServicesStatus.return = response;
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log('Service error');
    });
};
```

How could I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$scope.tag_chosen =[];

$scope.toggleSelection = function ( deviceId, $event ) {
   var checkbox = $event.target;
   var action=(checkbox.checked ? 'add':'remove');

    var idx = $scope.tag_chosen.indexOf( deviceId );

    // is currently selected
    if (action=='remove' && idx != -1 ) { 

        $scope.tag_chosen .splice( idx, 1 );

    }

    // is newly selected
    if (action=='add' && idx == -1 ) {

        $scope.tag_chosen.push( deviceId );
    }
```

and in html >>

```
ng-click="toggleSelection(yourcjeckbox value,$event)"
```